# Checking if an element(whos xpath location changes) is present using selenium IDE

Tags: testing, selenium, xpath, ide, automation

I am new to selenium. Is there anyway i could test if an element, for example an edit buttons is present in a page. There are multiple edit button and they all have different Xpath positions. Will it work if i use verifytext and give the value as "Edit"?

Comment: Could you add some HTML examples to you question?

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. What have you tried? What is the code and data you use?

Comment: I have one button to add information and this button is used to add information multiple times. But i am verifying that this button is only visible to admin, not any other users. So how do i check if that button is visible on an user other than admin? The buttons id keeps on changing and is not unique. 
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//section[@id='detailPane']/div/div[2]/div[14]/div[10]</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

 <td>click</td>
 <td>//section[@id='detailPane']/div/div[2]/div[14]/div[9]</td>
 <td></td>